# Adding a finally handler after promise creation results in uncaught promise rejection?

Tags: node.js, exception, promise

If I have a script like this

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, ms);
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    async function throwAfterOneSecond() {
      await timeout(1000);
      throw new Error("wow");
    }

    const p1 = throwAfterOneSecond()
    p1.finally(() => {
      console.log("finally handler");
    });
    await p1;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
})();
```

Then run it, this results in an unhandled promise exception

```
$ node test.js
finally handler
Error: wow
    at throwAfterOneSecond (/home/cdiesh/test.js:13:13)
(node:3657795) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: wow
    at throwAfterOneSecond (/home/cdiesh/test.js:13:13)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3657795) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3657795) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

However if I use

```
    const p1 = throwAfterOneSecond().finally(() => {
      console.log("finally handler");
    });
```

There is no unhandled promise exception, everything is fine

Does this behavior have any name? Running node v14.7.0

Comment: Not a complete answer but ..... No specific name for this behavior but it's a consquence of "branching". Remember that `p1.finally(...)` returns Promise, which branches off `p1`. It's more obvious if it is assigned, `let p2 = p1.finally(...)`. Now (maybe bizarrely) `await Promise.all([p1, p2])` will cause the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning to disappear.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense! I think it is sufficient to just await p2 at that point :)

Comment: Yes, brain in neutral. You would need `Promise.all([p1, p2])` if  `p1` and `p2` both branched from a `p0`.